Use jQuery to apply a CSS animation if the document width is greater than the window width
I have successfully applied an animation to my DOM (ID = flexRepeater) statically but I am having trouble doing it conditionally based on the size of the document and window. If the flexRepeater overflows the window, I'd like to enable an animation called 'marquee'. I already have the CSS keyframes for the animation defined in a stylesheet and tested, so that isn't the problem. Here's my code:


<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function applyAnimation() {
        if ( $(document).width() > $(window).width() ) {
          $("#flexRepeater").css("animation", "marquee");
} else {
          $("#flexRepeater").css("animation", "");
          }
         }
    $(window).resize(applyAnimation());
        applyAnimation();
});
  </script>
</body>



But I can't get the function to trigger at all. I never see the animation unless I go back to just applying it to the flex repeater without the if/else condition. Can anyone see why this wouldn't be working? If it matters, I am running this inside an Ignition 8.1 Perspective project (Ignition is an industrial automation / SCADA software).

Your question has already an answer but some how different.

try the below code it works,make sure the flexRepeater's width greater than window width
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  function applyAnimation() {
      var flexRepeater = document.getElementById('flexRepeater');
      var flexRepeaterWidth = flexRepeater.scrollWidth;// to check flexRepeater width
      console.log('flexRepeaterWidth');

      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

      if ( $(document).width() > $(window).width() ) {
        $("#flexRepeater").css("animation", "marquee");
      } else {
        $("#flexRepeater").css("animation", "");
      }
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', applyAnimation);

});

